# linear optimization using scipy failed

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, scipy-optimize

i need to maximize the throughput of a  network using `python`  `scipy`

```
class optimization():
    def __init__(self,nodes=nodes):
        self.nodes = nodes
        self.estimated_throughput_list=[] # list of throughputs
        for i in self.nodes:
            self.estimated_throughput_list.append(i.estimated_throughput) # adding for each node its throughput to the list
        self.d= np.ones_like(self.nodes, dtype=bool) # creating a boolean matrix having the same dimensions of the estimated_throughput_list

    def objective_function(self):
        """
        Objective function to maximize the sum of Di * xi,
        where Di is a binary variable that can take values of 0 or 1.
        x is an array of values for the variables x1, x2, ..., xn,
        and D is an array of values for the binary variables D1, D2, ..., Dn.
        """  
        return  np.dot(self.d, self.estimated_throughput_list)

    def constraint1(self):
        summation=8* 0.5 # erlang
        summation= summation+ np.dot(self.d, self.estimated_throughput_list)
        return summation
    def solution(self):
        return linprog(c=self.nodes,A_ub=self.estimated_throughput_list,b_ub=[8* 0.5],method="revised simplex")
```

i have a global list of nodes and each node containes it's estimated througput presented by `estimated_throughput`

the optimzation problem i am trying to solve is presented by the uploaded `figure:`[optimzation problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSr7V.png)

for simplicity `m *h^(-1)[PDR] is replaced by (8*0.5)`

in the main.py file i just call the function :

```
 opt=optimization()
    
 print("obj:",opt.solution())
```

it's my first  time applying optimization in python i don't know if this is the way to solve this type of problem.
if someone can guide me further in this problem that will be much appreciated.

the output was : `c = np.array(c, dtype=np.float64, copy=True).squeeze()  TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'myNode'`

Comment: what is the range of the node throughput values?

Comment: how many nodes do you have?

Comment: your use of `linprog` is incorrect because you haven't defined any integrality

Comment: Normally we expect the full error message, not just last line.  However given the `c` variable, I suspect it's in `linprog(c=self.nodes...`, and it's trying to convert your `self.nodes` variable into a numeric array.  Your global `nodes` contains strings or objects that don't represent numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means what the error says. If you have some class `myNode`, you can't use it as an input to the `scipy` methods. In your case that's probably happening in `c=self.nodes` which has both the wrong sign and the wrong type. This works fine:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy
from numpy.random import default_rng
from scipy.optimize import LinearConstraint

rand = default_rng(seed=0)
n = 12
nodes = rand.uniform(low=0.1, high=2, size=n)

m = 8
h = 2

result = scipy.optimize.milp(
    c=-nodes,  # maximize dot product
    integrality=np.ones_like(nodes, dtype=bool),  # everything integral
    bounds=(0, 1),
    constraints=LinearConstraint(A=nodes, lb=-np.inf, ub=m/h),
)

print('Node throughputs:')
print(nodes)
print()
print(result)
```

```
Node throughputs:
[1.31022721 0.61259476 0.1778497  0.13140251 1.64521345 1.8342356
 1.25260797 1.48604347 1.13288748 1.87663761 1.65012175 0.10520315]

        message: Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
        success: True
         status: 0
            fun: -3.994173190069585
              x: [ 0.000e+00  1.000e+00  1.000e+00  1.000e+00  0.000e+00
                   1.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  1.000e+00  0.000e+00
                  -0.000e+00  1.000e+00]
 mip_node_count: 44
 mip_dual_bound: -3.994173190069585
        mip_gap: 0.0
```